# ROS Melodic no longer finding python scripts

Tags: python, ros

I’m creating a project which will communicate with another companies ROS project. Originally, I was building it in Noetic but I was told they are using Melodic so I have to revert back to Melodic on mine. When I was running my packages in Noetic it ran fine … I used the following command:

rosrun gui_pkg main.py

However, when I changed over to Melodic for some reason it no longer can find the main.py so in order to run it, I need to run the following command:

rosrun gui_pkg scripts/main.py

That’s not a big deal but I am now running into errors finding other custom libraries. For example, the following import no longer works:

from gui_templates.tx_rx_display import TxRxDisplay

Any ideas of why this is now an issue? Btw, I also have the very simple talker.py/listener.py package from the ROS website that worked completely fine in Noetic but requires the "scripts/talker.py" in the rosrun command in order to run as well.

Some relevant info:

OS: Windows 10

folder layout under gui_pkg folder

- setup.py
- CMakeLists.txt
- package.xml
- scripts

  - main.py
  - gui_templates

    - tx_rx_display.py

CONTENTS of setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from catkin_pkg.python_setup import generate_distutils_setup

d = generate_distutils_setup(
    packages=[‘gui_templates’],
    package_dir={‘’: ‘scripts’}
)
setup(**d)
```

Below is a stripped down of the CMakeLists.txt for the gui_pkg (just removed most of the commented lines out)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(gui_pkg)

# Find packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
)

# for setup.py
catkin_python_setup()

# custom messages
add_message_files(
   FILES
   TerminalHeartbeat.msg
 )

# messages to generate
 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
 )

# didnt add any of these (didnt need in Noetic)
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES gui_pkg
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

# list of python files (all others are imported in main.py ... also the same as Noetic)
catkin_install_python(PROGRAMS
  scripts/main.py
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

# include directories
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

Comment: Were you always developing on Windows? Because ros1 installs aren’t exactly 100% stable on windows and shouldn’t be used if possible.

Comment: Btables, Yes, even the one that worked properly on Noetic was on this same Windows machine ... also, I am REQUIRED to develop on a Windows machine for my job because that is the machine they want me to use.  I don't have a choice on this matter. I did a simulator on a small personal Ubuntu machine and it works fine ... but like I said, I am required to use this machine so suggesting switching to linux isn't an option.

Comment: It being an unstable build is just something I try to always throw out; because it’s much more possible you’ll run into a problem that you can’t realistically solve.

Answer (score 1):

BLUF: Melodic uses Python 2 which requires a `__init__.py` file in each folder containing python scripts.

I found out what the issue is.  Melodic uses Python 2 by default and Noetic uses Python 3 by default.  I have only worked in Python 3 and didn't know that if I want to import a python file from a folder that you must include a `__init__.py` file in that folder (even if it is empty).

So to get it to work I just had to put a `__init__.py` file into the gui_templates folder, run catkin_make, source devel\setup.bat ... and then it worked.  I still need to type in: rosrun gui_pkg scripts/main.py but now if finds all the other python files.